# NetCDF4 [[--]] value for lat, long interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

Some of my requests to a netCDF4 object return a `[[--]]` value for invalid. The real numeric value for some locations is `[[someNumerical]]` . 
How can I catch this? It's not documented in the http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html `interp` documentation?

The reason why I am getting it is that my lat, long are out of bounds for reasonable interpolation, but I simply do not understand how to catch this return value.

Here's my call to it:

```
value = interp(theData, longitudes, latitudes, np.asarray( [[ convertLongitude(longitude)]] ), np.asarray( [[ convertLatitude(latitude) ]] ), checkbounds=True, masked=True, order=1)
```

Well, a workaround is of course to do

```
if str(value) == '[[--]]':
    doSomething
```

Comment: please add more specifics to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear as to where you think the problem is - in the values fetched via `NetCDF4`, or values returned by `interp`.

However when looking at the documentation for `interp` I find:

> masked
>   If True, points outside the range of xin and yin are masked (in a masked array). If masked is set to a number, then points outside the range of xin and yin will be set to that number. Default False.

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.interp

The `[--]` value makes sense in the context of `masked array`.

In a masked array, masked values (usually non-valid ones) are displayed with a `--`:

```
In [380]: x=np.ma.masked_greater(np.arange(4), 2)
In [381]: x
Out[381]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 --],
             mask = [False False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

You need to read up on masked array if you want to use the `masked=True` parameter.

You can do things like replace the masked elements with a fillvalue

```
In [387]: x.filled()
Out[387]: array([     0,      1,      2, 999999])
In [388]: x.filled(-1)
Out[388]: array([ 0,  1,  2, -1])
```

or remove them

```
In [389]: x.compressed()
Out[389]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

The fact that you are seeing `[[--]]` suggests that `values` might be a 2d array.  If so `compressed` might not be useful.

But a key point is that `values` array does not actually have `--` values.  That is what is displayed, as a filler.